# Homogeneous poisson process and identical distribution

Tags: poisson-process

> Suppose that the arrival of men and women at a bank can be considered independent homogeneous Poisson processes with mean 10 and 8 at every 30 minutes, respectively. In a interval of 10 minutes, what is the probability that the first two to arrive are men?

Let $X$ denote the number of men and $Y$ the number of women. Since we are supposing a homogeneous process, we have $X\sim Poi(\mu=10/3)$ and $Y\sim Poi(\lambda=8/3)$. The expected total number of arrivals are $n=\mu+ \lambda=10/3+8/3 = 6$. Thefore, probability of an arriving man is given by: $$p = \dfrac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda} = \dfrac{10/3}{6} = \dfrac{5}{9}$$
and the desired probability is given by $$P(\mbox{first two to arrive are men}) = p^2$$ given independence.

The problem i'm actually having is: Why is that? I can feel that the answer should be like this, but i'm not sure why. Why can i calculate the probability of an arriving man just like an equally probable space?

Comment: Be careful. $\frac{10/3}6 \ne \frac 5 6$

Comment: I've corrected that